# Printing the next 10 even and odd numbers ( java-script)

Tags: javascript

1) If I enter an even number, I want next 10 even numbers to be printed. If I enter an odd number, I want next 10 odd numbers to be printed.

2)If I enter an even number, I want previous 5 even numbers to be printed. If I enter an odd number, I want previous 5 odd numbers to be printed.

i am newbie to programming and trying to learn java-script myself, the above is the question i am trying to solve.  i am confused, i am not sure how to make the code to write the next 10 odd even number (i am referring to the first question).also the previous 5 (referring to second question).. below is my starting attempt. i am stuck

```
function isEven {
    var value = prompt("");
    if (value % 2 == 0) {
        for (var i = 2; i <= ; i = i + 2;)
            document.write(i + "<br>");
    }
}
isEven();
```

Comment: Don’t use `document.write`. You’ve got several syntax errors. Learn JS on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Comment: Whatever be the number why don't you just keep adding 2 to the input 10 times?

Comment: @Anu, this is a logical question buddy and you have some serious programming errors in your sample your code which are very basic to programming. First you need to learn some basic of basic of programming and then come to javascript. You may find it difficult at times to learn javascript if you do not know the core programming basics already.

Comment: thank you sir. i will study more of the basics and practice:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If I enter an even number, I want next 10 even numbers to be printed. If I enter an odd number, I want next 10 odd numbers to be printed.

```
function function1() {
    var value = prompt("");
    value = parseInt(value);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i = i + 1){
        value = value + 2;
      document.write(value   + "<br>");
    }
}
```

2)If I enter an even number, I want previous 5 even numbers to be printed. If I enter an odd number, I want previous 5 odd numbers to be printed.

```
function function2() {
    var value = prompt("");
    value = parseInt(value);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i = i + 1){
        value = value - 2;
      document.write(value   + "<br>");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this was the best answer that i understand with my current knowledge. i will study this more. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1:

```
if(number>=0){
for(i=2;i<21;i+=2){
   console.log(number+i);
}
}
```

Answer 2:

```
   for(i=2;i<11;i+=2){
       if((number-i)>=0){
           console.log(number-i);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify. You want to print both the previous 5 numbers and next 10 numbers of same 'evenness' for any given number?

In which case, you should do just that... You dont need to care if the number is even or odd, because the next/previous is always 2 away. (What you do when you cross 0 is up to you)

```
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        document.write((INPUT - (i*2)) + "<br>");        
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        document.write((INPUT + (i*2)) + "<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

refer this woking demo. hope this will help to you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<style type="text/css">


</style>

<body>

Enter a number : <input type="number" id="num">
<button id="butp" class="chk">print previous five numbers</button>
 || <button id="butn" class="chk">print next ten numbers</button>
<ul id="print">
 
</ul>





<script type="text/javascript">

$(".chk").click(function(){
 var the_id = $(this).attr('id');
 //alert(the_id);
 var theVal = parseInt($("#num").val());

 if (the_id =="butp") //this means user asking for previous
 {
  if (theVal==0 || theVal < 10) 
  {
   alert("cannot continue the operation, please enter a valid nubmer to continue");
  }
  else
  {
   for (var i=1;i<6;i++) 
    {
     newVal = theVal - (i*2);
     $("#print").append($("<li>"+newVal+"</li>")); 
    }
  }

 }
 else // this means user asking for next
 {
  for (var i = 1;i<11;i++) 
  {
   if (theVal==0) 
   {
    alert("please enter a valid number to continue");
   }
   else
   {
    newVal = theVal + (i*2);
    $("#print").append($("<li>"+newVal+"</li>"));
   }
  }
 }

});


$("#num").on('change keyup keydown', function(){
 theVal = $(this).val();

 if (theVal == "") 
 {
  $("#print li").css({"display":"none"})
 }
})


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function evenOdd(value) {
    if(value%2==0){
        console.log(`it's and even number ${value} next 3 digit will be`);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i = i + 1){
        value = value + 2;
      console.log(value);
    }
    }else{
        console.log(`it's and odd number ${value} next 3 digit will be`);
        for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i = i + 1){
        value = value + 2;
      console.log(value);
    }
    }
}

evenOdd(13)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).